# django ¿Cómo hacer que al editar el nombre de Persona cuando se cambie automáticamente se genere un registro en CambioNombre?

Tags: django, django-models

```
class Persona(models.Model):
    nombre = models.Charfield(max_lenght=100)
class CambioNombre(models.Model):
    pass
```

*La idea es que CambioNombre sea automático cuando se actualice Persona.nombre, y guarde nombre anterior y nombre nuevo *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes lograrlo haciendo uso de señales, suponiendo que tu modelo sea algo asi:

```
class Persona(models.Model):
    nombre = models.Charfield(max_lenght=100)

class CambioNombre(models.Model):
    nombre = models.Charfield(max_lenght=100)
    persona = models.ForeignKey(Persona, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Necesitas una señal pre_save, esta señal se ejecuta antes de guardar los cambios en la base, seria utilizarla de esta manera:

```
from django.db.models import models
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(pre_save, sender=Persona)
def historico_nombre(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.pk:
        # Estas editando a la persona ya que la instancia ya tiene pk

        # Almacenar la instancia con los datos actualizados
        obj_actualizado = instance

        # Obtener a la persona y sus datos sin cambiar
        obj_original = Persona.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)

        # Verificamos que haya cambiado el nombre
        if obj_actualizado.nombre != obj_original.nombre:
            # Entonces creamos un registro con el nombre antes de ser cambiado
            CambioNombre.objects.create(nombre=obj_original.nombre, persona=instance)
```